# How to use ‘many’ in sentence in different way?

Tags: grammar

I found this sentence from our regional daily. There is—

> He searched for a company where he can start working with his passion in coding. Coding hasn’t been favourite for many an ones.

Here,in last line last three words ‘many an ones’, how these are form? It could be said like ‘many people’. What is the issue using form like this?

Comment: Are you sure it was not a typing mistake made by them? Google does not show any results for "many **an** ones."

Comment: That sentence is clearly a mistake of some kind. (Although I'm not sure what it was meant to be. Even *hasn't been favourite* is incorrect. And *working with his passion **in** coding* is unidiomatic.)

Comment: The entire quoted passage is full of grammatical errors. I would not rely on this publication for examples of properly-used English.

Answer (score 0):

**Many an ones** is wrong English but the phrase **Many a one** means many people, and I think it must be used here.

> Coding has not been favourite for many a one.